# MDX Cube SQL Queries - Just want a row showing the Minimum price of a product in a city to show up, NOT all prices

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, min

I can't figure out how to prevent multiple rows to show up for each product.

Here is my code:

```
-- For each product find the city where it is offered at the lowest price
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MIN Price] AS MIN([Measures].[Price]) 

SELECT NON EMPTY { 
[Measures].[MIN Price] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
([Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * [Tb Supplier].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [DS715]
```

Here is a screenshot of what the results are.

[image]

> **I don't want to have each city show up, only the city with the lowest price**

I would like the query to return:

```
Boat     Wausau       3013.17
Computer Springfield  450.89
Gas      Wausau       2.28
Milk     Madison      3.88
Orange   Wausau       1.89
TV       Wausau       189.99
```

**EDIT: Tried to use order and rank with code below, but now shows one giant number for each Product name**

code:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Max Price RANK] AS 
RANK( ([Tb Product].[Name].currentmember), 
ORDER( ([Tb Product].[Name].currentmember), [Measures].[Price - Tb Transactions], BDESC) ) 

SELECT 
NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures].[Price - Tb Transactions] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
    filter([Tb Product].[Name].[Name], [Measures].[Max Price RANK] <2 )} ON ROWS 
FROM [DS715] 
WHERE ( [Tb Supplier].[City].&[Madison] )
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like you need to find a way to place the `distinct` keyword into your query.

Comment: @robbpriestley this is not SQL. MDX works diffrently

Comment: I wonder if it should even be tagged sql-server then?

Answer (score 0):

try the **generate** statement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/generate-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Price]}
ON COLUMNS, 
{
    Generate([Tb Product].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS,                             // foreach product
         [Tb Product].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER *                                    // cross the product
         BOTTOMCOUNT([Tb Supplier].[City].[City].ALLMEMBERS, 1,                    // with bottom 1 city
                       ([Tb Product].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Price])) // by product and price
    )
}

ON ROWS

FROM [DS715]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not work because you used Rank incorrectly. Make the following corections

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Max Price RANK] AS 
RANK( ([Tb Product].[Name].currentmember,[Tb Supplier].[City].currentmember), 
ORDER( ([Tb Product].[Name].currentmember,[Tb Supplier].[City].[City].members), [Measures].[Price - Tb Transactions], BDESC) 
) 

SELECT 
NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures].[Price - Tb Transactions] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
    ([Tb Product].[Name].[Name],filter([Tb Supplier].[City].[City], [Measures].[Max Price RANK] <2 )} 
    ON ROWS 
FROM [DS715]
```

Comment: @obizues did the above help?